# Animation depending on a property

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

Is there any way to execute an android animation progressively depending on a property?. Let's say for example fading an imageView while swiping from the first to the second page of a ViewPager. But I want the fading to be related to the swiping. I hope that I made my question understandable. I would like to have both general answers and for the specific example.

Comment: sure: `ViewPager.PageTransformer` and / or `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener`

Comment: Yes but I want for example if the page swipe is on 50% the fading to be on 50%

Comment: tried `PageTransformer` ?

Comment: I am asking this question in general. I would like to know if there is a specific methodology for progressive animations

Comment: from the docs: *"A PageTransformer is invoked whenever a visible/attached page is scrolled. This offers an opportunity for the application to apply a custom transformation to the page views using animation properties."*